# How do you execute a stored procedure using Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, castle-activerecord

I believe there is a discussion on this very topic somewhere on the net but I lost the url and I am unable to find it via googling.

What I might try right now would be:

```
ISessionFactoryHolder factoryHolder = ActiveRecordMediator<EntityClass>.GetSessionFactoryHolder();
ISession session = factoryHolder.CreateSession(typeof(EntityClass));
try
{
    IDbCommand cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "spName";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    factoryHolder.ReleaseSession(session);
}
```

However, I am not quite sure if this is the correct way to do this or if perhaps a better way exists.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (stored procedure with params and dynamic result table):

```
// get Connection
System.Data.IDbConnection con = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder()
                                                    .GetSessionFactory(typeof(Autocomplete))
                                                    .ConnectionProvider.GetConnection();

// set Command
System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "name_of_stored_procedure";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// set Parameter of Stored Procedure
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter param = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@parameter_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Value = "value_of_parameter";
((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection)cmd.Parameters).Add(param);

// call Stored Procedure (without getting result)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// ... or read results
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader r = (System.Data.SqlClientSqlDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(r.Read()) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("result first col: " + r.GetString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The blog I used when implementing stored procedures in my ActiveRecord code was this post by Rodj (http://blog.rodj.org/archive/2008/05/23/activerecord-nhibernate-and-sql-stored-procedures.aspx).  Using his post and the comments I was able to get this to work.  I haven't decided if this is the best way yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get an IDbConnection with:

```
ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder()
    .GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase))
    .ConnectionProvider.GetConnection();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it says that ConnectionProvider doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveRecord version 1, this works:

```
IDbConnection connection = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder()
                          .GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase))
                          .OpenSession().Connection;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ArrayList DevolverCamposDeObjetoSTP(T Objeto, List<Consulta> Consultas, string StoredProcedureName)
    {
        ArrayList results;
        try
        {
            var queryString = @"EXEC " + StoredProcedureName;
            foreach (var consulta in Consultas)
            {
                switch (consulta.tipoCampo)
                {
                    case Consulta.TipoCampo.dato:
                        queryString = queryString + " " + consulta.Campo + " = " + "'" + consulta.Valor + "'";
                        break;
                    case Consulta.TipoCampo.numero:
                        queryString = queryString + " " + consulta.Campo + " = " + consulta.Valor;
                        break;
                }   
                queryString = queryString + ",";
            }
            queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Count() - 1, 1);
            var query = new HqlBasedQuery(typeof(T),QueryLanguage.Sql, queryString);
            results = (ArrayList)ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(exception.Message);
        }
        return results;
    }
public class Consulta
{
    public enum TipoCampo
    {
        dato,
        numero
    }
    public string Campo { get; set; }
    public TipoCampo tipoCampo { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string Indicador { get; set; }
}
public void _Pruebastp()
    {
        var p = new Recurso().DevolverCamposDeObjetoSTP(
                                                         new Recurso(),
                                                         new List<Consulta> { new Consulta { Campo = "@nombre", tipoCampo = Consulta.TipoCampo.dato, Valor = "chr" }, new Consulta { Campo = "@perfil", tipoCampo = Consulta.TipoCampo.numero, Valor = "1" } },
                                                         "Ejemplo");
    }
```